# What does extent do within imshow()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram2d

Im wanting to use imshow() to create an image of a 2D histogram. However on several of the examples ive seen the 'extent' is defined. What does 'extent' actually do and how do you choose what values are appropriate?

Comment: Please learn to read the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extent defines the images max and min of the horizontal and vertical values. It takes four values like so: extent=[horizontal_min,horizontal_max,vertical_min,vertical_max].

Comment: but in this example ive seen online that doesnt seem to be the case. [link](http://www.physics.ucdavis.edu/~dwittman/Matplotlib-examples/)

Comment: on the page you link to `extent` has the value `[-6.0, 4.0, -4.0, 6.0]`, which is exactly what Gael specified.